# Specific MySQL Select Query to PDO Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got this select Query in mySQL. Trying to change it to PDO. This question is not exactly a duplicate because other answers don't exactly show how to do this.

```
$check_pic = mysql_query("SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
      $get_pic_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_pic);
      $profile_pic_db = $get_pic_row['profile_pic'];
      if ($profile_pic_db == "") {
      $profile_pic = "img/default_pic.jpg";
      }
      else
      {
      $profile_pic = "userdata/pp/".$profile_pic_db;
      }
```

If there is nothing stored in the profile_pic field in the users table, then the variable $profile_pic should be the default image, if there is a location stored in profile_pic in the users table, then it should be $profile_pic = "userdata/pp/".$profile_pic_db;

Side Question:

Lastly, a side question, do I have to type 'try', 'catch' & 'new PDO' for every insert query? like so;

```
$server = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$dbn = "databasename";

try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dbn", $user, $password);

// set the PDO error mode to exception
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (name)
VALUES (:name)");

$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);

$name = $_POST['name'];

$stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$db = null;
```

Comment: What is the question? You don't have a select currently written in PDO.

Comment: far as I can see, you're probably mixing a `mysql_`  query with PDO, correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: you're also putting the horse before the wagon here `$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);

$name = $_POST['name'];` and using the wrong variable `$user, $password)` <<< for your password.

Comment: @chris85 Question is how do I do the select query (the mysql one) in PDO...
Fredd -ii-  and Im not mixing PDO with mysql_..
yes the variable names are not important for the question im asking.,..

Comment: There are clearly 2 questions. How do I do the mysql Query in PDO and secondly do I need to put try and catch clause around insert queries everytime?

Comment: You do it like you are doing your insert.. Your insert is a mysql query. You don't **need** to do a try catch ever..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use try/catch every time, only when you want to detect some unexpected error, like for example Invalid SQL query. Try catch block is used in the connection to catch and manipulate errors in case of connection error ( bad username, password, server not found etc. )

For example, if you have a wrong in the SQL query like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INVALID profile_pic FROM users WHERE username = :username");
```

This will throw an exception that you should catch:

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INVALID profile_pic FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    $userData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Invalid SQL Query";
}
```

But if you're completely sure that the query is correct, you don't have to use it.

About the first question:

```
<?php
$connectionData = [
    "server" => "localhost",
    "user" => "",
    "pass" => "",
    "database" => ""
];

$username = $_POST["username"];

$db = null;

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $connectionData["server"] . ";dbname=" . $connectionData["database"], $connectionData["user"], $connectionData["pass"]);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();

$userData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$profilePic = "img/default_pic.jpg";


if($userData != false) {
    if(array_key_exists("profile_pic", $userData) && !empty($userData["profile_pic"])) {
        $profilePic = $userData["profile_pic"];
    }
}

if($db !== null) {
    $db = null;
}

?>
```

When the result from the sql query must be only 1 row ( as it is in this case ) use LIMIT 1 ( more performance ). If you don't use LIMIT 1 and your field is not unique, all entries will be checked for matches.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

> public bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )
>
> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), **the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute()** is called.

The second argument of bindParam is variable passed by reference so, there is no really a problem define the variable after the binding (it must be declared before the execute() ). But I think it's a bad practice.
In case you use bindValue, then you must declare the variable before the binding.

You can write a function or a method to make the sql query with try/catch block so you don't have to write it every time:

```
<?php
$connectionData = [
    "server" => "localhost",
    "user" => "",
    "pass" => "",
    "database" => ""
];

$db = null;

function sqlQuery($query, array $data, $db) {
    $stmt = null;

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindParam(':' . $key, $value);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $stmt = null;
    }

    return $stmt;
}

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $connectionData["server"] . ";dbname=" . $connectionData["database"], $connectionData["user"], $connectionData["pass"]);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


$profilePic = "img/default_pic.jpg";
$stmt = sqlQuery("SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1", array("username" => $username), $db);

if($stmt != null) {
    $userData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(isset($userData) && $userData != false) {
        if(array_key_exists("profile_pic", $userData) && !empty($userData["profile_pic"])) {
            $profilePic = $userData["profile_pic"];
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "SQL Error";
}


echo $profilePic;

if($db !== null) {
    $db = null;
}
?>
```

In this case I only have to use the function **sqlQuery**, inside of the function the statement is build and if there is any kind of error is catched and null will be returned as response.

Comment: Thank you, just what I wanted, perfect. You have a great day sir.

Comment: My connect script is in a different php file `<?php include ("connect.inc.php"); ?>`

Is it better to use `include` or `require_once('connect.inc.php');`

Comment: [Require](http://php.net/require)
`require is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue. `

So include will produce a warning in case the file is not found and require will produce fatal error. 
The diffrence between include_once/require_once is that if the file is already included it wont be included second time.
So I'll recommend you require_once. You should include this file only one time and you must have it.